# Неправильно редактируется матрица

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы, таблицы, pillow

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, надо сделать скрипт для перегонки png файлов в таблицы, написал такой код:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("level.png")
pixels = im.load()
x, y = im.size
level = [[1] * x] * y

for j in range(y):
    for i in range(x):
        if pixels[i, j] == (128, 64, 0, 255):
            level[j][i] = 7
        elif pixels[i, j] == (237, 28, 36, 255):
            level[j][i] = 2

with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(level).replace('], ', '], \n').replace('], ', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
```

Вроде бы всё нормально проверяет, видит пиксель всего один раз, но при этом заносит его не по определённому индексу а сразу по всей колонне, так что это

[image: прекрасная картинка]

Превращается в вот это
[image: ещё более прекрасная картинка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании матрицы из единиц вы множество раз дублируете ссылку на один и тот же объект. Поступите проще, используйте numpy:

Вместо

```
level = [[1] * x] * y
```

сделайте

```
import numpy as np
level = np.ones((x,y))
```

Либо, если вам не хочется использовать дополнительные библиотеки, сделайте матрицу при помощи генерации списков:

```
level = [[1 for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)]
```